# Vagrant Up: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`. Not enough arguments for "import" command

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox

I am attempting to setup a Linux instance on Windows 10 and I'm encountering the following error. I am using Vagrant 1.8.6 and VirtualBox 5.1.6. I have tried multiple boxes and get the same results, I've tried it in git bash or in cmd and as administrator and not.

**Run in Empty Folder:**
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
vagrant up

**Result:**

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "-n", ""]

Stderr: Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 5.1.6
(C) 2005-2016 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage import           <ovfname/ovaname>
                            [--dry-run|-n]
                            [--options keepallmacs|keepnatmacs|importtovdi]
                            [more options]
                            (run with -n to have options displayed
                             for a particular OVF)


Syntax error: Not enough arguments for "import" command.
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is not enough information at this point.
Can you please run vagrant in debug mode?

```
set VAGRANT_LOG=debug
vagrant up
```

That should provide more information.